# How to reliably extract URLs contained in URLs with Python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, url, urlencode

Many search engines track clicked URLs by adding the result's URL to the query string which can take a format like: `http://www.example.com/result?track=http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

In the above example the result URL is part of the query string but in some cases it takes the form `http://www.example.com/http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` or URL encoding is used.

The approach I tried first is to split `searchengineurl.split("http://")`. Some obvious problems with this:

- it would return all parts of the query string that follow the result URL and not just the result URL. This would be a problem with an URL like this: `http://www.example.com/result?track=http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask&showauthor=False&display=None`
- it does not distinguish between any additional parts of the search engine tracking URL's query string and the result URL's query string. This would be a problem with an URL like this: `http://www.example.com/result?track=http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?showauthor=False&display=None`
- it fails if the "http://" is ommitted in the result URL

What is the most reliable, general and non-hacky way in Python to extract URLs contained in other URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from urllib import unquote

urls =["http://www.example.com/http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", 
"http://www.example.com/result?track=http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask&showauthor=False&display=None", 
"http://www.example.com/result?track=http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?showauthor=False&display=None",
"http://www.example.com/result?track=http%3A//www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask%3Fshowauthor%3DFalse%26display%3DNonee"]

def clean(url):
    path = urlparse(url).path
    index = path.find("http")
    if not index == -1:
        return path[index:]
    else:
        query = urlparse(url).query
        index = query.index("http")
        query = query[index:]
        index_questionmark = query.find("?")
        index_ampersand = query.find("&")
        if index_questionmark == -1 or index_questionmark > index_ampersand:
            return unquote(query[:index_ampersand])
        else:
            return unquote(query)

for url in urls:
    print clean(url)

> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?showauthor=False&display=None
> http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?showauthor=False&display=None
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try using `urlparse.urlparse` it will probably get you most of the way there and a little extra work on your end will get what you want.

Comment: would `urlparse.parse_qs` be helpful?  Or are you looking for something more robust?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Python specifically, but I would use a regular expression to get the parts (key=value) of the query string, with something like...

```
(?:\?|&)[^=]+=([^&]*)
```

That captures the "value" parts.  I would then decode those and check them against another pattern (probably another regex) to see which one looks like a URL.  I would just check the first part, then take the whole value.  That way your pattern doesn't have to account for every possible type of URL (and presumably they didn't combine the URL with something else within a single value field).  This should work with or without the protocol being specified (it's up to your pattern to determine what looks like a URL).

As for the second type of URL... I don't think there is a non-hacky way to parse that.  You could URL-decode the entire URL, then look for the second instance of http:// (or https://, and/or any other protocols you might run across).  You would have to decide whether any query strings are part of "your" URL or the tracker URL.  You could also **not** decode the URL and attempt to match on the encoded values.  Either way will be messy, and if they don't include the protocol it will be even worse!  If you're working with a set of specific formats, you could work out good rules for them... but if you just have to handle whatever they happen to throw at you... I don't think there's a reliable way to handle the second type of embedding.